# Get first and last values that are not zeros from array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have the following array that is generated dynamically with integers. So I do not know it's values or how many values it has.

```
var myArray = [0,0,5001,0,5002,5003,0,5004,0,0]
```

And I am trying to get the first value that is not zero and the last value that is not zero. In this case:

**first value = 5001
last value = 5004**

Is there a way to do that without using a for loop? Or maybe by creating an extension for the array class?

If there's any answer here on stack for that please let me know and I will remove the question. Haven't found anything in here yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension Array where Element: IntegerType {
    var firstPositive: Element? {
        for number in self {
            if number > 0 {
                return number
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    var lastPositive: Element? {
        for number in reverse() {
            if number > 0 {
                return number
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
let myArray = [0,0,5001,0,5002,5003,0,5004,0,0]
myArray.firstPositive   // 5001
myArray.lastPositive   // 5004
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray = [0,0,5001,0,5002,5003,0,5004,0,0]
let filteredArray = myArray.filter { $0 != 0 }

print("First value = \(filteredArray.first ?? 0)")
print("Last value = \(filteredArray.last ?? 0)")

/*   First value = 5001
     Last value = 5004   */
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
let myArray = [0,0,5001,0,5002,5003,0,5004,0,0]
let noZeros = myArray.filter{$0 != 0}
let firstValue = noZeros.first
let lastValue = noZeros.last
```

But notice that there *is* a loop hidden in that code; you can't possibly do this without a loop *somewhere*. The only way to do this is to look at every value in the array, and that implies a loop.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, you can use a filter statement to accomplish this.

That means *you* don't have to write a for loop, but the filter statement still has to loop through every item in the loop.

Worse, the filter statement creates a new array. That's a needless allocation. Furthermore, the filter statement iterates through *every* item in the array. With a couple of loops that break when they find the first non-zero value you would be able to accomplish the same thing without iterating through anything other than the outer zeros. From each direction you'd stop at the first non-zero value. For a large array that becomes computationally significant.

Comment: Just a note: we are not, _per se_, using the `map` statement, but `filter` (to avoid confusion for OP). The point about redundant allocation naturally holds for `filter`. Out of curiosity, regarding needless allocation: is this the case also for `map`, when array size is unchanged? Given `arr = arr.map ...`.

Comment: Yup. I realized that after I posted, and was in the process of fixing it. Thanks for keeping em honest.

Comment: Map is probably worse, since I think it takes every object in the source array and creates a replacement object in the destination array.